# Maximum of $\frac{xy^2z}{x^4 - y^4 + z^4}$ with positive variables

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, rational-functions

What's the maximum value of the equation
$$
\frac{xy^2z}{x^4 - y^4 + z^4}
$$

with $x, y, z > 0$?

I have tried to divide it with $x + y + z$ but nothing came out of there.

Answer (score 1):

It is unbounded.  To see this, notice that the values of $x^4+z^4$ and $xz$ are always positive and independent of $y$.  Thus, it is sufficient to consider the function
$$f(y) = \frac{ay^2}{b-y^4},$$

which clearly approaches $\pm \infty$ as $y \rightarrow b^{1/4} = (x^4+z^4)^{1/4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $x = y = 1$ and $z = 1/t$. Then your expression becomes $t^3$ and thus is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a slight variation of the answer given by [J.-E. Pin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/89374/j-e-pin)

Let $x = y = 1$. Then your expression becomes $\Large \frac{1}{z^3}$. For positive values of $z$, this expression becomes arbitrarily large as $z$ approaches $0$.